# ASP.NET Windows Authentication prompting for credentials for just one user

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I'm using `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` to retrieve user information. I want this to happen automatically without the user being prompted by their browser for credentials.

In IIS, I have ASP.NET impersonation and Windows Authentication enabled and then Anonymous Authentication disabled:

[image: IIS Authentication settings]

This has been working to silently retrieve user details in this application for 3 years. Yesterday, however, a single user started getting prompted for credentials in all browsers.

Is there an AD issue or a browser setting that can force a prompt rather than automatically passing credentials like everyone else? What could their issue be?

Comment: if there is a new issue then probably must be with only one browser - do you have check that with different browsers ? eg I have notice that google chrome stop redirect http page to https when its inside iframe and miss the cookies... but only chrome.

Comment: @Aristos - I have confirmed that this happens in all major browsers. Simply resetting or reinstalling the browser hasn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally discovered that there was something wrong with the user's profile on the machine. We wiped the profile and set it back up again and it works and intended now.